# how to download pentaho database model and reporting engine?

Tags: java, grails

i am using grails 3.1.1 to build my own application..

when i use grails 2.1.1, i used this jar file to run and compile pentaho report.

- pentaho-report-model-5.1.0.0-752.jar
- pentaho-reporting-engine-classic-core-5.1.0.0-752.jar

but now, i am trying to use grails 3.1.1

i tried to download with add this code to my build.gradle, but i cannot download that file.

```
compile 'pentaho:pentaho-database-model:5.1.preview.506'

compile 'pentaho-reporting-engine:pentaho-reporting-engine-classic-core:5.1.preview.506'
```

i tried to refresh dependencies..and i get this.

```
C:\Users\User\Documents\311\VPCnotificationServer>grails refresh-dependencies
> Configuring > 0/1 projects > root project > Resolving dependencies ':classpath
1/1 projects > Resolving dependencies ':agent' > Resolving dependencies 'detache

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 7.172 secs
> Resolving dependencies ':testRuntime' > Resolving dependencies 'detachedConfig
| Error Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':testRuntime'. Typ
e 'gradle dependencies' for more information

C:\Users\User\Documents\311\VPCnotificationServer>
```

Comment: Well those dependencies check out. Have you tried running `grails refresh-dependencies `?

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa see my update post, i tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Aha!** The problem is that those artifacts are not in Maven central. They're in the Pentaho Maven repository. I confirmed this with a dummy Groovy script:

```
@GrabResolver(name='pentaho', root='http://repository.pentaho.org/artifactory/repo/')
@Grab('pentaho:pentaho-database-model:5.1.preview.506')
@Grab('pentaho-reporting-engine:pentaho-reporting-engine-classic-core:5.1.preview.506')

class Hello {
    def speak() {
        println 'Hello'
    }
}

new Hello().speak()
```

So all you need to do is add the Pentaho Maven repo to your project. Simply edit **build.gradle** like this:

```
repositories {
    ...
    maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
    maven { url "http://repository.pentaho.org/artifactory/repo" 
}
```

Comment: must i change it from maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" } to maven { url "http://repository.pentaho.org/artifactory/repo" } ?
how about another grails plugin?

Comment: i mean is it possible to download another grails plugin after i change  maven url to repository.pentaho?

Comment: Oh no! Don't change it. I meant to *add* the Pentaho entry.

Comment: Oh, crap. Let me clarify. Use this: `pentaho { url "http://repository.pentaho.org/artifactory/repo" }`

Comment: i get this error: "Build file 'FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
 where* C:\Users\User\Documents\311\VPCnotificationServer\build.gradle' line
: 8"

line 8 : pentaho { url "http://repository.pentaho.org/artifactory/repo" }
:(

Comment: Hmm, is that semi-colon really in there, or is it a typo?

Comment: Oh, goodness, forgive me for screwing up. I had it right the first time. You'll end up with two maven entries. I updated my answer to make it clearer.